# How to Pass data to autocomplete child component from parent component in angular

Tags: c#, angular, angular11

I have two components. I need to pass the data to autocomplete component from parent to child when I select the value from another autocomplete dropdown. Here I have attached the code. Please help me to find a solution to resolve this

---

```
Parent Component Html
  <div class="col-md-6">            
        <mat-label>Name<span class="astric">*</span></mat-label>
       <mat-form-field  appearance="outline" class="autocomplete">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Select UserName" aria-label="Number"  matInput (keyup)="onAutocompleteKeyUp()" formControlName="userName" [matAutocomplete]="auto">      
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let existingUser of filteredOptions | async" [value]="existingUser" (click)="onExistingUserChange(existingUser)" >
          {{existingUser}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>   
    </div>
<div class="col-md-6">     
<app-time-zone  [timeZone]="timeZone" (newItemEvent)="addItem($event)"></app-time-zone>                
</div>
Parent Component TS
onExistingUserChange() {
    this.timeZone = "India Standard Time";                   
  }
Child Component HTML
<form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field  appearance="outline" class= "pull-right">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [(ngModel)] = 'tZone'>      
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" (click)="onSelectionChange()" [value]="option">
          {{option}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
Child Component TS
 onSelectionChange(): void{
    let timezoneid_arr = this.timezoneresp.filter((zone:any)=>zone.viewValue == this.tZone)
    let zoneid = timezoneid_arr[0]['value']
    this.newItemEvent.emit(zoneid);    
  }
```

---

Comment: We can use @Input() and @Output() decorators in Angular to share data in parent and child components.
https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Comment: yea I tried using Input parameter but its not working
@Input() timeZone: any;

Answer (score 0):

**Use EventEmitter**

1. In the HTML, call the child component like below

   ```xml
   <app-emp-dashboard (emitEvent)="receiveMessage($event)"></app-emp-dashboard>
   ```

   [As Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGUz9.png)
2. In the TypeScript code of the parent component:

   ```
   @Output() emitEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();
   ```
3. And to pass the data:

   ```
   // Get Info. and pass to parent //

   passDataToParent = (details) => {   
       this.emitEvent.emit({ details: details});   
   }
   ```